# [Python][Selenium] Error on ".find_element_by_class_name.click()"

Tags: python, selenium, click, selenium-chromedriver

Written below is my Python Selenium test code. It searches "Dubai to singapore" on google.com. It worked fine.

However, I encountered following error when I amended code to following 2 ways:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1. Remove line No.8 and 9

   I removed those lines because I thought these are not essential.

   Except for this, nothing has changed on the code.
2. Search "Dubai to singapore by Walking"

   I just added 'by walking' at the end of searching keyword.

   Except for this, nothing has changed on the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/en")

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Dubai to singapore")
print(driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").get_attribute("value")) #print: Google Search
print(driver.find_element_by_name("btnI").get_attribute("value")) #print: I'm feeling lucky
search_button = driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")
search_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with PyAutoGUI (make sure to install it first)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/en")

driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Dubai to singapore by walking")
pyautogui.keyDown('enter')
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because `search_button = driver.find_element_by_name("btnK")` is hide due to the list. if you want to solve this problem please refer below code.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout("10")
driver.get("http://google.com")
element=driver.find_element_by_name("q")
element.send_keys("Dubai to singapore")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
```